# Prevent Inserting to same names into MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

How can i prevent inserting a value into database if it is already exist with the same name in it? echoing alert that this name already exist
for example DATABASE has [MARY, MIKE, JOHN] and then someone tried to INSERT the name [JOHN] again, I want to prevent that from happening, Even if he changed the letter style [JoHn]

Comment: Find if a row with such name exists.

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41079899/edit) your question and post your code as well

Comment: `The following two statements illustrate that string comparisons are not case sensitive unless one of the operands is a case sensitive (uses a case-sensitive collation or is a binary string)` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Comment: By the way... why are you trying to add such a limit? There are plenty of people who have the same name/surname. In fact, it's rare for someone to have a really unique name/surname. Also - have you read [Falsehoods programmers believe about names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)?

Comment: @Vilx- It was just random examples, Sorry about that.

Comment: Ahh, OK then. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a UNIQUE index on the column(s) and make sure the column has a case-insensitive (preferably accent-insensitive too) collation. That should do it, I think.

If you try to SELECT first and see if the name is there, you can run afoul of a "race condition". Basically there's a small amount of time between you running the SELECT and INSERT, and someone else can manage to INSERT the name during that. It's a small chance, but it's there, and eventually it will bite you. You can counteract this with a transaction (be careful about the isolation level your transaction uses), but why bother when an index is so much simpler and easier? Also, you'll need an index on that column anyway if you want your check to be fast.

Comment: I've made this code `$chk= "SELECT name, lastname FROM data WHERE name = '$name', lastname= '$lastname'";`
And used UNIQUE index as you represented, May i ask if it is not troublesome, How to make this code depends on both name and last name? Because it always uses name as check only, And i want If both name and last name exist to be prevented.

Comment: Well, you can include several columns in the index. See [`CREATE INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html). In that case it will check that the combination is unique. So you can have several JOHNs and several SMITHs, but only one JOHN SMITH. Mind you, it gets trickier with people who have three names. "JOHN"+"PETER SMITH" and "JOHN PETER"+"SMITH" will be different names, but when you show them on screen they might seem the same (depends on how you show them).

Comment: oh no no, I just used lastname as example and not for an input for name and last name, just like secondary name, Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

When defining a table `UNIQUE` may be specified for a given column so a duplicate entry attempt will result in an error (the INSERT query will fail).

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;
```

Normally default collation for a `varchar` is case insensitive (checking would not be bad however).

---

Another option is to first execute a `SELECT` query to find if a record with the same field value already exists and then perform a second `INSERT` query if no rows are found or display an error otherwise

Comment: This day and age using a charset which is NOT Unicode is strongly discouraged. You'll only get problems that way.

Comment: sure... changed to UTF8

Comment: Fair enough! 

Comment: Btw - the default collations for MySQL can be changed at various levels. When running this script, better still double-check that the default collation is what you think it is. Personally I prefer being explicit about it, but it's a matter of preference.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER if_exists BEFORE INSERT ON table_name
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(SELECT name FROM table_name WHERE LOWER(name) = LOWER(NEW.name)) THEN
        SIGNAL sqlstate '45000' SET message_text = 'Error! User already exists.';
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Replace `table_name` with the name of your table and `name` with the name of the attribute you want to compare.
Signals are supported by MySQL 5.5 and above.

Answer (score 0):

Before insertion, select from table where username LIKE username